# How to nest rows in a column with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to code in such a way that even when the screen is as small as mobile screen the layout looks good.

Below is how i tried coding it

```
<div class="row" id="slide_show">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img id="img1" src="img1.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img id="img1" src="img2.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img id="img1" src="img3.jpeg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6" id="Tiles">
        <img id="img_tiles" src="Calendar.gif" />
        <div class="textbox">
          <p class="text" align="center"><i><b>Events at calendar 
            <br />click to know the details about events this year..</b></i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6" id="Tiles">
        <img id="img_tiles" src="travel.jpg" />
        <div class="textbox">
          <p class="text" align="center"><i><b>Events at calendar 
            <br />click to know the details about events this year..</b></i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6" id="Tiles">
        <img id="img_tiles" src="vacancy.jpg" />
        <div class="textbox">
          <p class="text" align="center"><i><b>Events at calendar 
            <br />click to know the details about events this year..</b></i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6" id="Tiles">
        <img id="img_tiles" src="info.jpg" />
        <div class="textbox">
          <p class="text" align="center"><i><b>Events at calendar 
            <br />click to know the details about events this year..</b></i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
 #Tiles {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s; 


  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  padding-left:0px;

    margin-left:30px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top:40px;
  position:relative;
}

#Tiles .textbox {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  margin-left:-210px;
}

#Tiles:hover .textbox {
  margin-left:0;
}

#Tiles img {
  margin-left:0;
}

#Tiles:hover img {
  margin-left:210px;
}

.text {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

#Tiles img, .textbox {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

#img_tiles{
 width:200px;
 height:165px;
 padding-top:0px; 
 padding-bottom:15px;
```

}

The result looks good on desktop and tablets, but on smaller screens the tiles on the right end are displayed below the slide show vertically. What should I do to display them horizontally? or at least like two tiles in a row. That's the reason I used col-xs-6

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without your `css` codes.

But you could try changing your extra small column class to `col-xs-12` so it would take the whole width instead of having `50%` of it.

So you end up with this sample code :

```
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="Tiles">
    <img id="img_tiles" src="info.jpg" />
    <div class="textbox">
       <p class="text" align="center"><i><b>Events at calendar 
          <br />
          click to know the details about events this year..</b></i>
       </p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

And do that to other classes.

Comment: Thank you Robin Carlo. just now I add the CSS code as well.